# Putting in the wrong math equation into the line of code?

Tags: c++, math

I am supposed to be using the monthly interest rate formula: https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Wpb.jpg, where rate is the monthly interest rate that I wrote as interestRate, N is the number of payments which I wrote as amountOfPayments, and LoanAmt is the amount of the loan.

and when I try putting this in my program to calculate the interest, I end up getting a monthly payment that is way larger than it should be. I presume my line of code where I put the formula in is formatted incorrectly. Here is my code:

```
monthlyPayment = interestRate * pow(1 + interestRate, amountOfPayments) / pow(1 + interestRate, amountOfPayments) * borrowAmount
```

Comment: instead of trying to do everything in one line of code, consider breaking it into more variables. `top` and `bottom` could be set prior then it is just `(top/bot)*borrowAmount`

Also parenthesis are free... dont be afraid to use too many

Comment: I just started C++ and don't really know much. I don't know what top and bot mean. How would you format the parentheses if you are only using one line of code?

Comment: You've left out a set of parentheses and a term from your source. Copy exactly.

Comment: Since you didnt put any types in your question ill just give an example with ints 
`int top = interestRate * pow(1 + interestRate, amountOfPayments)`
`int bot = pow(1 + interestRate, amountOfPayments) -1`

Comment: You'll have to change the type of the variables appropriately... ints will, of course, truncate your values

Comment: Okay, where should I put the part where the result of the fraction is multiplied by LoanAmt?

Comment: so after you set up top and bot correctly you should be able to do 
`monthlyPayment = (top/bot) * borrowAmount`

Comment: After parentheses enclosing everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `double` as the data type and following the formula in the image, the code can be like this:

```
double common_rate_power = pow(1 + interestRate, amountOfPayments);
double monthlyPayment = (interestRate * common_rate_power * borrowAmount) / (common_rate_power - 1);
cout << monthlyPayment << endl;
```

Note that I have stored the `pow` calculation in another variable since it is used twice in the formula.

Answer (score -1):

The numerator and denominator are not organized.

Excuse me, I wrote wrong codes.

Comment: This is just giving me a result of $0.00 now.

Comment: This is exactly what he already has with redundant parentheses and the same missing term. Have a look at the source formula.

Comment: It is still wrong, worse than ever in fact. When (and if) you fix it, please don't leave the incorrect version to confuse everybody. Wrong answers are of no use or interest.